# Segue takes long time to perform

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I've got a `UITableViewController` with contacts and when clicked on the contact I want to perform a segue from the tableviewcontroller to the actual controller.

This is the code that I run at `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

{
  // A lot of code, but it's basically saying: dependent of the section and whether you're searching or not, store the name and number you've selected.

  number = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  if(indexPath.section == 0 && [self.usersWithNamesAndNumbers count] > 0){
    if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive) {
      index = [[self.searchDisplayController searchResultsTableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];
      name = [[self.searchedUsersWithNamesAndNumbers allKeys] objectAtIndex:index.row];
      number = [[self.searchedUsersWithNamesAndNumbers allValues] objectAtIndex:index.row];
    } else {
      index = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
      name = [[self.usersWithNamesAndNumbers allKeys] objectAtIndex:index.row];
      number = [[self.usersWithNamesAndNumbers allValues] objectAtIndex:index.row];
    }
  } else {
    if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive) {
      index = [[self.searchDisplayController searchResultsTableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];
      name = [[self.searchedContactNamesWithNumbers allKeys] objectAtIndex:index.row];
      number = [[self.searchedContactNamesWithNumbers allValues] objectAtIndex:index.row];
    } else {
      index = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
      name = [[self.contactNamesWithNumbers allKeys] objectAtIndex:index.row];
      number = [[self.contactNamesWithNumbers allValues] objectAtIndex:index.row];
    }
  }

  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"moveToView" sender:self];
  [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

And I've got some code in the `prepareForSegue` method as well:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
  if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"moveToView"]){
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDidComeFromContacts:YES];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setNameLabelContents:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,", name]];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setPhoneNumberLabelContents:number];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setText:@"Segue text"];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setCardId:@"EDf8oCCol2"];
  }
}
```

It takes about 2-3s to process this code. I've also got 2 other segues to the same VC, and those take about 1s less long, but still 1-2s. Could this have anything to do with the setup inside the `destinationViewController` or is it the setup before the segue?

Many thanks

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that should take nearly that much time. Are you doing any long running operations in the destination controller's init or viewDidLoad methods?

Comment: I'm reading the contacts in the `viewDidLoad` method. I'm testing with about 1.500 contacts in the simulator. Could that be an issue? I'm not doing it on the main thread

Comment: Try commenting out that code, and see if it gets faster.

Comment: it's not. Should I drop the `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: So, it didn't get faster when you commented out the reading contacts code? Are you doing anything else in viewDidLoad?

Comment: No it didn't get any faster.. I'm initializing a toolbar, and doing a little bit of specific layout for an `UIView` and `UIButton`, setting some bools and selectors. Not really anything fancy. I am however importing a lot of headers (about 8 of them).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64101/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-bdv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to a long running operation in the initWithCoder method of the destination view controller. Move that code into viewDidAppear, as well as any code in viewDidLoad that depended on the result of that code in initWitCoder. This should allow the segue to complete quickly. Ultimately, you will need to try to fix whatever the problem was with that slow running method if possible.